# Why is cURL hanging after sending and receiving an HTTP 100 Continue code, not continuing with the body?

Tags: php, curl

I am currently putting together some data and making a POST request to my local web server (Apache 2.4.27).

Here's how I'm putting together the request:

```php
public function sendPost($url, array $data) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $httpCodes = parse_ini_file(CONF::HTTP_CODES_INI);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['data' => json_encode($data)]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    //Ignore SSL issues, testing on a dev box
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
    $curlInfo["http_code"] = $httpCode . ': ' . $httpCodes[$httpCode];
    if ($result === false || $httpCode > 299) {
        $result = json_encode($curlInfo);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

This is the conversation I see from cURL

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my.local.server.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /path/script.php?action=receive HTTP/1.1
Host: my.local.server.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 2645588
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------051580b0f5143de8

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
```

However, while debugging the script on the server, I do actually get the data and the request seems to go through all of the way.  From my understanding the `HTTP 100 Continue` status code, cURL should only send the header first, see the `continue` response, and then send the data.

You can see above that the client receives the `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue`, but then it times out.

I've tried setting the timeout time to 5 minutes, and it still just hangs until timeout.

Any ideas?

Edit: I'ved tried to use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
```

to try and force the `continue` expectation to not be set.  The response is the same, just without the `Expect: ...` part.

Comment: it says "0 bytes **received**" and that's probably the key. It may very well have sent all bytes, but it didn't receive anything... (well, after the "100 continue" that is)

Answer (score 2):

got a few theories, 1: maybe a bug in curl. 2: maybe a bug in the server, where the server stops reading, and the receive buffer runs full, curl waiting for the server to read, which never happens, and it times out... 3: maybe you have a slow connection, and sending 2645588 bytes really takes over 5 minutes.

you should add a CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION to check the transfer speed, this could hopefully rule out or confirm theory 2 and 3, like

```
$starttime = microtime ( true );
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS => false,
        CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION => function ($ch, int $expectedDownloadBytes, int $bytesDownloaded, int $expectedUploadBytes, int $bytesUploaded) use (&$starttime): int {
            var_dump ( 'runtime seconds:', microtime ( true ) - $starttime, 'uploaded so far:', $bytesUploaded, 'expected to upload:', $expectedUploadBytes );
            return 0;
        } 
) );
```

- if that doesn't yield any clues, you could create a POST request manually with socket_create & co, but i don't have an example to show you now (due to an accidental deletion of a few misc script folders some time back, on a compressed btrfs partition, i tried recovering em, but nothing :( )